# auto detect proxy parameters, and then grab them manually using Firefox

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, auto-detect

With the "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network" option in Network Proxy Firefox's preferences, I can connect through the proxy I'm used to use.

but I want to get the Proxy connection parameters to use them outside Firefox.

How can I see the proxy server address:port or the PAC file path auto-detected by Firefox ?

EDIT : I'm running on Linux Ubuntu. To be more general, I'm also looking for a way to find the PAC file address of my network.

Comment: Which system are you using ?

Comment: If on Linux, Type `echo $http_proxy` or `echo $https_proxy` . It's a system wide variable and will show you what you need !